# Can Javascript call anything in iOS when a certain event fires?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ios4, websocket

I'm implementing an iPhone App that uses WebSockets (inside a hidden UIWebView), so I need some communication between Javascript and Obj-C.

I'm aware of the [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString] method and that's great for sending websocket responses, but I was thinking more along the lines of "when an event fires in JS, let iOS know". I would be using this concept to trigger iOS to do stuff when it receives a certain websocket response.

Any ideas on how to solve such a problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best and only way to do this is to do a window.location.href in JS when the event is fired, and use the WebView method:

```
(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

You can then capture the URL and decide whether or not to reload the page. Then use the URL to take the appropriate action on the Objective-C side of things. More details [here](http://www.app-solut.com/blog/2011/05/ios-interfacing-webview-content-via-javascript/):

Comment: If anyone finds any better ways, post it here.